# Where can I find the js code of polkadot pallet?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

As we can see in polkadotjs, when we add pallet then we can see interaction interface as shown in image below. But how this code is generated? Where can I find the code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code for the pallet specifically is not in JavaScript, it is written in Rust. The code for this UI is located in [this repo](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps). The pallets emit type metadata that components in the apps repo utilize to construct the UIs you are using.

Comment: hey @Drew Stone thanks for this information. I review [page-nfts](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/page-nfts) code but haven't found `create()` function and haven't found any parameters which are passed inside `create()` function.

Comment: It's because you're actually on [page-extrinsics](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/page-extrinsics). And as mentioned, you might find that a lot of this logic is automatically (magically) generated from the type metadata. These extrinsic calls especially. It's just one giant data (JSON) blob that says what pallets have what extrinsic calls/state calls/rpc calls, etc.